# How to install any windows software on Ubuntu 17.10 using wine that requires Microsoft Framework 4.6 and Above?

Tags: wine, compatibility

I need to install a software that requires `Microsoft Framework 4.6`. I have installed the latest version of `wine` on Ubuntu 17.10.

I need a way to install `Camtasia`, but when I run the setup wizard, I receive an error saying: `Microsoft Framework 4.6` or higher is required.

Comment: And you are sure Camtasia runs with wine? The rating for any release is garbage: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=7983  so I reaaaaaaaaaaally doubt it is going to work. -far- better option: install virtualbox, a valid copy of windows in that and Camtasia in that.

Comment: What about running Adobe Premier / Sony Vegas